# How can I insert chinese infro into Document with Java2word?

Tags: java, java2word

When I use [java2word](/questions/tagged/java2word) to insert Chinese info into a document, but the lib still give me a wrong code named doc, So I want to know which charset is used in `java2word` when it process with Chinese.
My workspace charset is `utf8`, so I tried change Chinese string to `GBK,ISO-8859-1`, even `GB2312`, but the `java2word` doesn't work well, it gives me different charset named doc, and those are all displayed with wrong code.

My version:

```
ms word 2013 simple chinese
jdk 1.7.0.55
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be encoding issue. Have you read this page: https://github.com/leonardoanalista/java2word/wiki/Encoding-Tips-and-Tricks

How many characters do you need to add? if you need a few, you can use the encoded representation of them. However you need the whole document, this would require some extra research.

thanks
Leonardo